# JMeter - Change Font Colour

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

Cannot believe I need to ask a question regarding this, but I cannot find anything on Google. Everything related I find is basically only regarding the font `SIZE` OR the `THEME`.

While changing to the `Darklaf - Dracula` theme is great, reading the code (Groovy script, XML, JSON) is AWFUL.

Hoping someone has a way of changing the `FONT COLOUR`, because looking at the below will make me go insane.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that this is a crazy issue, and I'm not sure why there isn't more discussion on it or bugs being raised...

The issue is with the darklaf libraries, I can demonstrate this by changing the version that JMeter uses to v2.4.8 rather than v2.5.4.

This is what my custom version looks like:
[image: See how nice it looks...]

To change this, either build JMeter from source after changing the version in `gradle.properties`, which is what I did, or I suppose you could download the .jar file and replace the version in `jmeter/lib`, which I haven't tried but there's no reason why it shouldn't work.

Happy automating.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much Jake! :)

This may seem a bit simple, but I cannot seem to find `gradle.properties`.. I am using `JMeter 5.3`. But also, where would I be able to find the `.jar` file for a different version (assuming the `.jar` you're referring to is for Darklaf Theme)?

Comment: Ah right, sorry I assumed you were building it from source like I am!
No worries, just add the .jar to the jmeter/lib folder.

Comment: You can find the versions here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.weisj.
Just replace each version inside your current jmeter/lib folder with the 2.4.8 version you download from that site.
Note: darklaf-extensions-rsyntaxarea is version 0.3.4

Comment: Should be fixed, when https://github.com/apache/jmeter/pull/719 is merged.